# Running Nginx proxy for Kestrel AspNet5

Tags: curl, nginx, asp.net-web-api, proxy, kestrel-http-server

I am having some troubles running Nginx server to proxy requests to Kestrel. In Kestrel i can see responses coming relatively fast, bust Nginx for some reason waiting til timeout to return the response.

Here is my proxy conf:

```
server {
 listen   80;
 server_name    192.168.163.143;
 access_log     /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
 location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000;
 }
}
```

ngic.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
events{
worker_connections 768;
}
```

I run kestrel with default arguments to run application on port 5000.

Giving it to be requested from browser at 192.168.163.143 does not return a json until timeout.

I have tried curl my endpoint and what i have found is:
Direct Kestrel call returns whole batch of data at once, while Nginx call returns a portion of json and stucks...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was quite simple. RC1 of Kestrel does not work with closed connection, therefore you have to keep alive ur connection.

In the location section of ur proxy configuration, add `proxy_set_header Connection ""`